# ::ng-content deprecated in Angular4

Tags: css, angular

As we all know, Angular4 is moving away from shadow piercing descendant combinators.
I still have to support IE11 so CSS variables aren't an option.
I have the following code though :

```
block.component.html:

<div class="decorators">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>

app.component.html:

<block>
  <h1>foo</h1>
  <hr />
  <p>blah</p>
</block>
```

I want all `hr` inside my block to have `"border-top: 2px solid red;"`

What's the best place to use it then ?
I can't put in my `block.component.css` without using `::ng-deep`

```
EDIT:
It would be working in my `app.component.css` as long as the blocks are directly in its template, and not wrapped up in another component.
```

So my only option left is to use it my global `main.css`. I am not keen on that solution either as I would then have some css put a bit everywhere to style the same component.
What's my best option here ?

Comment: Doesn't hr {border-top: 2px solid red;} inside app.component.css work ? I am missing a detail maybe

Comment: You right, that would work, I am editing my answer